# Creating array with mmap function. Assembler x86_64 AT&T

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, mmap, system-calls

I want to create an array that will contains for example 4 values
Here's my code:

```
mov $32,%rsi # 4 x 8bytes
mov $9,%rax
mov $0,%rdi
mov $0x3,%rdx
mov $0x01,%r10
mov $0,%r9
syscall
```

Now I am having a new adress of alocated 32 bytes in rax?

When I am trying to put something into it , for example:

```
mov $0,%r14
mov $3,%rdx
mov %rdx,(%rax,%r14,8)
```

It gives me SIGSEGV error

Comment: What is the value of `rax` after the syscall? Is it `MAP_FAILED` (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)? Also, for a system call the system call # goes in `rax` and the arguments go in order into the registers `rdi    rsi    rdx    r10    r8     r9`. For `void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);` this means addr->rdi, length->rsi, prot->rdx, flags->r10, fd->r8 and offset->r9. Why are you not setting r8?

Comment: rax had 0xfffffffffffffff7 after the syscall. r8 was default as 0 , I've changed it into -1 `mov $-1,%r8` and set r10 to 3 (map_anonymous) now I have received rax `0xffffffffffffffff`(map_failed)

Comment: You _must_ keep the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag and OR into it `MAP_ANONYMOUS`. The rule is that exactly one of either `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED`, but not both, must be specified, and _in addition_ zero or more other flags, including `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

Comment: Now I put 1 into r10 `mov $1,%r10` as `MAP_PRIVATE` , the rax after syscal is now `0xffffffffffffffed` , but still when I want to do an operation on this `mov %rdx,(%rax,%r14,8)` it gives me SIGSEGV error

Comment: You did not do what I told you to do. I specifically told you that for `flags` you must set it to `MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS`, whatever the value of that is on your system. I'll emphasize that you're not meant to replace one with the other, you're meant to combine the two by a bitwise OR.

Comment: I have found that `MAP_PRIVATE` is 0x1 and `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is 0x3, after OR operation on 01 and 11 I got 11 which is the same as 0x3. I've tried putting 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 number in r10 always ending with SIGSEGV error.

Comment: How odd. Recap: You're right now attempting `mmap(0, 32,  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)`. This should definitely work... Have you tried compiling a C program that performs this call and see where your code differs in register setup? For that, on Linux there's the `syscall` function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mmap` expects 6 arguments, but you only pass 5. You forgot to set up `r8` for the file descriptor. Assuming you want to allocate anonymous memory, this should be set to `-1` and of course the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` should also be set in the flags.

PS: if you have the C library available, the easy way to allocate memory is to just call `malloc()`.

Comment: r8 was 0, I've changed it to -1 `mov $-1,%r8`, and set r10 to 3 (map_anonymous). After syscall rax is 0xffffffffffffffff - map failed. I want to do it without C library

Comment: `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is `0x20` and `MAP_PRIVATE` is `0x02` ([see kernel source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/asm-generic/mman-common.h?id=79319a052cb0ae862954fe9f6e606417f1698ddb)) ... not sure where you got the wrong values from. So `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE` gives `0x22`.

Comment: OP did not specify the system he's on, and the values given for both flags were alien to me, but now is the time to ask... For that matter, [here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/bsd/sys/mman.h?v=xnu-2050.18.24#L117) are the values for Mach; `#define MAP_PRIVATE     0x0002` and `#define MAP_ANON        0x1000`. @Piodo, on what system are you developing? Linux? Mac? Something entirely different?

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu Linux. I've put 0x22 into r10 and it seems that it works. Thank you both Jester and Iwillnotexist Idonotexist for wasting your time for noobie like me . I really appreciate your help. Thanks